# How to change the name of terrafrom resource in tf file wiithout terrafrom registerring a change in plan?

Tags: terraform

today I imported my cloud instance to terraform

```
resource "linode_domain" "example_domain" {
  domain = var.primary_domain_name
  soa_email = var.domain_soa_email
  type = "master"
}
```

After I imported the instance to terrafrom using the `terrafrom import` command. I realized I was suppose to name example_domain as primary_domain.

Now if I change example_domain to primary_domain directly in the tf file the `terrafrom plan` registers as change in the plan, which I do not want to! so i want to know how can I rename this resource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easies way to rename a resource would be to make a copy for resource block with the new name and then run a `terraform state mv` command.

So, in your case, we duplicate the resource with a new name:

```
resource "linode_domain" "example_domain" {
  domain = var.primary_domain_name
  soa_email = var.domain_soa_email
  type = "master"
}

resource "linode_domain" "primary_domain" {
  domain = var.primary_domain_name
  soa_email = var.domain_soa_email
  type = "master"
}
```

We run `state mv`:

```
terraform state mv linode_domain.example_domain linode_domain.primary_domain
```

We remove the old (`example_domain`) resource block from the code.

The procedure above is also documented in the official Terraform [docs](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/mv#example-rename-a-resource) for `state mv`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Terraform v1.1 or later then you can use [the new config-based refactoring features](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/refactoring), which specifically means a `moved` block in this case:

```
resource "linode_domain" "primary_domain" {
  domain    = var.primary_domain_name
  soa_email = var.domain_soa_email
  type      = "master"
}

moved {
  from = linode_domain.example_domain
  to   = linode_domain.primary_domain
}
```

The above configuration tells Terraform that if it finds an object in the prior state bound to the address `linode_domain.example_domain`, it should pretend that it was instead bound to `linode_domain.primary_domain` before making any other decisions.

Terraform will include an extra annotation on the planned changes for that resource to say that its address changed, but should not propose any changes to the remote object itself unless you've also changed some other settings in the resource block.

Comment: thanks for the useful info, I used first answer already .